# How to solve InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project I have a `LevelGenerator` creating `Stages` (game objects) and adding these to a list. When I am dying I want to destroy and remove all items in the list. But when I am iterating through the list, only the first object is destroyed and removed, then an error happens:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException (System.ExceptionResource resource) (at :0)
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNextRare () (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)   System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNext () (at :0)

Could you help me?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART  = 25f;

    [SerializeField] private Transform Startingstage;
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> StageList;
    [SerializeField] private Transform player;

    public List<GameObject> gameObjectsToDestroy;
    public bool creatingGoesOn = false;

    private Vector3 lastEndPosition;

    public void CreateEnviroment()  // Every time called when game is started
    {
        lastEndPosition = Startingstage.Find("EndingPoint").position;

        int startingSpawnLevelParts = 7;

        for (int i = 0; i < startingSpawnLevelParts; i++)
        {
            SpawnLevelPart();
        }

        creatingGoesOn = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (creatingGoesOn)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, lastEndPosition) < PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART)
            {
                // Spawn a new level part if player is to close to the end.
                SpawnLevelPart();
            }
        }
    }

    private void SpawnLevelPart()
    {
        Transform randomStage = StageList[Random.Range(0, StageList.Count)];
        Transform lastLevelPartTransform = SpawnLevelPart(randomStage, lastEndPosition);
        lastEndPosition = lastLevelPartTransform.Find("EndingPoint").position;
    }

    private Transform SpawnLevelPart(Transform stage, Vector3 spawnPosition)
    {
        Transform levelPartTransform = Instantiate(stage, spawnPosition,  Quaternion.identity);
        gameObjectsToDestroy.Add(levelPartTransform.gameObject);
        return levelPartTransform;
    }
}
```

Inside the error script:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.transform.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        destroyEnviroment.creatingGoesOn = false;
        Debug.Log(destroyEnviroment.gameObjectsToDestroy.Count);

        foreach (GameObject toDestroy in destroyEnviroment.gameObjectsToDestroy)
        {
            destroyEnviroment.gameObjectsToDestroy.Remove(toDestroy);
            Destroy(toDestroy); //Somewhere here is the error
            Debug.Log(destroyEnviroment.gameObjectsToDestroy.Count);
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `foreach (GameObject toDestroy in destroyEnviroment.gameObjectsToDestroy.ToList())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're removing items from a list as you're iterating over them, and this changes the size of the list!

The easiest way to do this would probably be

```
foreach (GameObject toDestroy in destroyEnviroment.gameObjectsToDestroy)
{
    Destroy(toDestroy);
}
destroyEnviroment.gameObjectsToDestroy.Clear();
```

**Edit:**
It's worth noting that here I `Destroy` before removing, this might seem counter-intuitive but the reason is calling destroy will set the object to be destroyed at the end of the frame, we can then forget about it and clear the list - and everything else will be taken care of.
I'm a big advocate of not removing items from lists if you don't need to - in this case you're clearing the whole list so you might as well use `clear()`

Comment: Thx. But why doesn't work this with a while loop (list.Count > 0) where I destroy and remove element [0] from the list? In my case It always appears: "Not in Range".

Comment: @Thboss Ill update my answer to respond to this

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you see `InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` where the collection in question is being accessed on a single thread you should know that it is because you are modifying the same list for which you are iterating over

This often happens when making use of a functionality that uses `IEnumerable` such as:

- `foreach` loops as in your case
- `GetEnumerator()` directly and using that to iterate through the collection

The common solution in the case of 'foreach' loops is to consider a different construct that makes sense to your problem.

I can also provide a method of applying this in your case if needed. Just let me know.

Comment: But in this case you don't really need to change the loop type, what Jay suggested for clearing it outside the loop suffices in your case. Sometimes it might not work in some situations. Another option I tend to use is `while(collection.Any)` if you know you want to clear every item in the list. Keep in mind some data types might be `O(n)` if you are removing elements from the beginning such as a `List`.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Unity and this is extremely pushing me forward. U da best!